# Default sonar rule set is trashed by upgrade how to restore or download?

Tags: php, upgrade, sonarqube

After upgrading my Sonar installation to version 3.7 my rules are all turned off. This is probably because I had troubles with an older PHP plugin and removed it during upgrade. The change log is displaying the changes that everything is turned off.

How do I easily re-enable it or restore the default rule set?

I was using the default 'Sonar way' rule set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by installing Sonar in a virtual machine, using the default test database. Then installing the PHP plugin. Then exported the ruleset which I needed by using the permalink and saved the XML.